# Extremely high nonpaged pool memory in Task Manager is far greater than poolmon.exe's values

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

My RAM used on bootup is exorbitantly high...to the point where I'm almost using all 8 GB as soon as I sign on to Windows 10.

I'm monitoring my memory usage with poolmon.exe (comes with the Windows 8.1 Driver Kit) and I'm not sure if I'm seeing the correct values.

The highest three values are 33, 15, and 10 MB...everything else is below 10 MB. What's using all my memory?

Am I misunderstanding something here? Also, as far as I've read on here and other places, 4.2 GB of non-paged pool memory is exorbitant and indicative of a driver leaking memory. Not sure if that's accurate or not.

[image: Task Manager Values]

[image: Poolmon values]

Comment: Task manager, add column NP pool, does that show anything?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Umm, not sure that's available in Win10. Where would it be at?

Comment: Details tab, right click on column headers, select columns

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **Pool usage**, in scenario select **Boot** (iterations 1) and click on **Start**. This captures the pool usage during boot and I can see where the usage comes from. After the reboot, zip the large ETL file as 7z/RAR, upload the file to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry to not keep this updated, but I wasn't sure where to continue. Basically my non-paged pool is down to 180 MB every time I turn it on/use it now. I have been having a lot of trouble in general with my computer so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is/was. For what it's worth, I did recently update my graphics driver. 

Also, a few days ago I got a BSOD saying "Page fault in non paged area." Sorry for the kind of random assortment of information but my computer has just been all sorts of out of whack lately.

Comment: ok, if you are able to repro it again, try to take the trace.

Comment: were you able to reproduce it or is the issue now solved?

Comment: @magicandre1981 the issue is now solved, I wasn't able to reproduce it. Thanks for the help, though. For what it's worth, my computer was randomly shutting off because of a broken power supply. I haven't had memory issues since then, either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue can't be reproduced and seams to be fixed. So the question is obsolete.

Comment: Just FYI, "Page fault in non paged area" has nothing to do directly with nonpaged pool. It may have to do with something that should have been put in nonpaged pool, but wasn't.